# MOZ_LOG for network traffic not working with headless mode on GeckoDriver with Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, headless, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to run Selenium Firefox tests on a server(headless mode) but while running it I want to use Moz Log to get all the network traffic. Here is a sample of my code in which I paste this map for the moz log and the file to put the log in:

```
public static FirefoxDriver getFirefoxGUI(Map map) throws IOException {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/root/firefox_driver/geckodriver");
GeckoDriverService service;
        GeckoDriverService.Builder builder = new 
        GeckoDriverService.Builder();
        service = builder.usingAnyFreePort()
                .withEnvironment(map)
                .build();

        service.start();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
        firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
        options.setHeadless(true);

        options.merge(capabilities);

        return new FirefoxDriver(options);
    }
```

The thing is when I construct the FirefoxDriver with (options) it runs in headless mode but the logs aren't recorded and when I start it with (service) it records the logs but it doesn't run in headless. I tried merging options with service like this: options.merge((Capabilities) service) but I get an exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities. Any help how I can combine these two?
Thanks!

Comment: Code trials for `logs to be recorded`?

Comment: @DebanjanB Please elaborate?

Comment: I mean to ask what exactly do you mean by `logs aren't recorded` and `records the logs`? Do you essentially mean shows up in the console?

Comment: @DebanjanB by logs I mean the network traffic: all the APIs that are called and all the cookies.